# get key and value of associative arrays

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

My problem is that i want to get key and value from an assosiative array, but i only can find how to get the value from the key. This is what i find:

```
DECLARE
 TYPE assoc_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30)
 INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);

 state_array assoc_array;
BEGIN
  state_array('Alaska') := 'Juneau';
  state_array('California') := 'Sacramento';

  dbms_output.put_line(state_array('Alaska'));
  dbms_output.put_line(state_array('California'));

END;
```

This prints Juneau and Sacramento, but i want something like this:

```
DECLARE
 TYPE assoc_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30)
 INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);

 state_array assoc_array;
BEGIN
  state_array('Alaska') := 'Juneau';
  state_array('California') := 'Sacramento';

    for x in 1..state_array.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(state_array(x).key || state_array(x).value);
    end loop;
END;
```

Is that possible?. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually there is a way, kindly consider the code bellow

```
declare
   type assoc_array is table of varchar2(30) index by varchar2(30);

   state_array assoc_array;
   l_idx varchar2(30);
begin
   state_array('Alaska') := 'Juneau';
   state_array('California') := 'Sacramento';

   l_idx := state_array.first;
   while (l_idx is not null) loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Key = ' || l_idx || ':Value = ' || state_array(l_idx));
      l_idx := state_array.next(l_idx);
   end loop;
end;
```

The output will be

```
Key = Alaska:Value = Juneau
Key = California:Value = Sacramento
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this using associative arrays. Because, see below.

```
DECLARE
 TYPE assoc_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30)
 INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);

 state_array assoc_array;
BEGIN
  state_array('Alaska') := 'Juneau';
  state_array('California') := 'Sacramento';

    for x in 1..state_array.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line('x ='||x);
    end loop;
END;
```

would print 
x = 1
x = 2

There is no way for oracle to know that x = 1 = Alaska.

You should use binary array to do something like this.

Comment: The array count is `2`, your loop is running from 1 to 2, because of that it is outputing the `x = 1 x = 2`. This has nothing related to the array key values. Also always loop the associative array with `while` loop, instead of `for loop`, this will keep you of from the errors.